# where to post questions about history, language, and culture of karate

Tags: discussion

I'm a karate instructor looking to supplement my instruction on skills and techniques with knowledge about the history, culture, and language. For instance, I found this snippet from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karate) intriguing:

> [In the 1920s] the name was changed from 唐手 ("Chinese hand" or "Tang hand")[8] to 空手 ("empty hand") – both of which are pronounced karate in Japanese

But I feel the factoid by itself is too sparse to pass along without the historical context of the relationship between Okinawa, China, and Japan (about which I know nil). What is the appropriate location/tag to post such questions on the history, language, and culture around - but not the practice of - karate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any such questions should be posted on the [main site](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/). Tags can always be altered later, but I  suggest [karate](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/karate), [history](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history), and [japanese](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese).

Welcome!